# Error with buildozer, # Command failed: git config --get remote.origin.url

Tags: android, git, kivy, windows-subsystem-for-linux, buildozer

Hi 1st time using buildozer, get this git error in subject/topic.  Not expert on git so not sure what it means.  I did do some searching and got a response regarding a possible missing switch --repo?  Not sure how to get it to set it.  Verbose output follows.  Blotted out system name etc...  I'm using wsl under windows 10.  Up until now, everything did seemt to be working.  Thanks for any help.  Log level in spec was set to 2.

```
(venv-buildozer) nemo@workstation:/mnt/c/Users/powow/Documents/python/kivy/FlappyTypeGame$ buildozer -v android debug
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Read available permissions from api-versions.xml
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.19.7 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /mnt/c/buildozer/venv-buildozer/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-13-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-13-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'git config --get remote.origin.url'
# Cwd /mnt/c/Users/powow/Documents/python/kivy/FlappyTypeGame/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
# Command failed: git config --get remote.origin.url
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/sh'
#     WSL_DISTRO_NAME = 'ubuntu'
#     NAME = 'workstation'
#     PWD = '/mnt/c/Users/powow/Documents/python/kivy/FlappyTypeGame'
#     LOGNAME = 'nemo'
#     MOTD_SHOWN = 'update-motd'
#     HOME = '/home/nemo'
#     LANG = 'C.UTF-8'
#     WSL_INTEROP = '/run/WSL/8_interop'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     VIRTUAL_ENV = '/mnt/c/buildozer/venv-buildozer'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'nemo'
#     SHLVL = '2'
#     PS1 = ('(venv-buildozer) \\[\\e]0;\\u@\\h: '
 '\\w\\a\\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\\[\\033[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00m\\]\\$ ')
#     WSLENV = ''
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = '/home/nemo/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/mnt/c/buildozer/venv-buildozer/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/nemo/.local/bin/'
#     MAIL = '/var/mail/nemo'
#     HOSTTYPE = 'x86_64'
#     OLDPWD = '/mnt/c/Users/powow/Documents/python/kivy/FlappyTypeGame/.buildozer'
#     _ = '/mnt/c/buildozer/venv-buildozer/bin/buildozer'
#
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I have experimented a little more and have found a way around this problem.  The folder my project was in was located in my user folder in c:\Users.  This folder in my wsl environment has root ownership and root group.  I was running the build command using a non root user as was advised by buildozer itself.  To be more clear, I was running the 'buildozer -v android debug' in my windows user folder under wsl using the non root user.  This resulted in the error I experienced for this question.

To fix this, I copied the project folder to my new non root linux account home folder and changed location to the project folder.  The copy of the folder in my non root user home folder had the non root user and group as owners.

I then reran the 'buildozer -v android debug' again and it completed the build!

I'm not sure why the git command fails when the user running the build isn't the same as the owner of the folder the project is in.  If someone could explain why the git command doesn't work when the folder/file owner doesn't match the user running the buildozer command, that would be helpful.  Thanks.  I have been able to reproduce this 2x to verify this solution works.

to repeat, my system is win 10 and I'm using wsl to run ubuntu.  I have setup the buildozer env under wsl.